# Laravel SoftDeletes conflicts with Eloquent ORM

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, soft-delete

As the title says it all, I will still guide you to reproduce the issue. Details are below.

#### Steps to reproduce

1. Clone Laravel official project from [Github](https://github.com/laravel/laravel)
2. Install all dependencies of Php

   - `composer install`
3. Make the necessary models with migrations

   - `php artisan make:model Post -m`
   - `php artisan make:model Comment -m`
4. Make the models relations

   For `App\Post.php`, we will create relation with `softDeletes`

   ```php
   use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

   class Post extends Model
   {
       use SoftDeletes;

       public function comments()
       {
           return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
       }
   }
   ```

   For `App\Comment.php`, we will create relation with `softDeletes`

   ```php
   use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

   class Mention extends Model
   {
       use SoftDeletes;

       public function post()
       {
           return $this->belongsTo(Post::class);
       }
   }
   ```
5. Let's jump now to the migrations

   For `2019_08_29_230505_create_posts_table.php`,

   ```php
   Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
       $table->bigIncrements('id');
       $table->string('title');
       $table->string('content');
       $table->timestamps();

       $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
       $table->softDeletes(); // <-- notice that I use the softDeletes here as well -->
   });
   ```

   For `2019_08_29_240305_create_comments_table.php`,

   ```php
   Schema::create('comments', function (Blueprint $table) {
       $table->bigIncrements('id');
       $table->string('post_id');
       $table->string('content');
       $table->timestamps();

       $table->foreign('post_id')->references('id')->on('posts');
       $table->softDeletes(); // <-- notice that I use the softDeletes here as well -->
   });
   ```
6. Now, populate some post and comments from your database.
7. When I try to dump, `Post::find(1)->comments` it returns nothing/no record.
8. But when I remove the `softDeletes` from `App\Comment` and dump again, it shows the comments belongs to the Post with an ID of 1.

---

I hope I explain it well. Feel free to ask question if you don't understand anything.

Comment: How are you populating post/comments in your database? Are you ensuring that `deleted_at` IS NULL and not some other value?